# How to use multiple spacing in single UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have an array of strings, I make a string from the array objects

```
let stringForLabel = arrayContaingStrings.joined(separator: "\n")
```

But when I show this it in a single UILabel, it is hard to read as below
[image]

The 6th and 7th lines in the above label are a single line as

```
 Nowy Dwor Mazowiecki, Poland
```

But due to screen width is shown in 2 lines. So I would display it in the following format

[image]

How can I achieve this spacing in UIlabel? I have tried increasing line spacing in storyboard but then it increases all line spacing in the label. (The content in both images are different, I just wanted to show the line spacing in both cases)

Comment: If they are all in different labels, you can increase the spacing between the labels in layout?

Comment: It is a single UILabel

Comment: Why do you need it to be in a single UILabel?

Comment: because there are many other contents like labels, textview, button etc are present down to this UIlabel and Now the height of UIlabel changes according to content.

Comment: You can still attach those content below the last UILabel if you have every word in a label individually. If your problem is that it is a pain to create labels dynamically and set up constraints for them, then yes it is.

Comment: `let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.init(); paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 8.0; let attributedString = NSAttributedString.init(string: stringForLabel, attributes: [.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle, .font: theFontYouWant]); label.attributedText = attributedString`?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, Its dynamic content

Comment: check this  one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498344/objective-c-label-line-spacing

Comment: @Larme Thank you, It works :) if you can post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective C label line spacing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498344/objective-c-label-line-spacing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paragraph is detected by the `\n` newline character. The line spacing between paragraphs and line spacing for `lineBreakModes` will be different.

You can use the [paragraphSpacing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1532528-paragraphspacing) to add extra spacing between paragraph compared to `lineBreakMode` spacing.
Also try `lineHeightMultiple`.

Apple Docs link is provided above.

Try this **UILabel Extension**:

```
extension UILabel {

func setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0, lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat = 0.0) {

    guard let labelText = self.text else { return }

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 10

    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString
    if let labelattributedText = self.attributedText {
        attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: labelattributedText)
    } else {
        attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
    }

    // Line spacing attribute
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

    self.attributedText = attributedString
}
}
```